# Can chef-solo be run as a non root user

Tags: oracle, weblogic, chef-infra, chef-solo

When I run chef-solo as a non root user, I get the below error:

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/chef/chef-client-running.pid
```

Is there a way to get around this?

When I run my recipe as root user, then I get the below from my recipe.

The current user is root & has special privilages.
The Oracle Universal Installer can not continue with the installation.

Please help.

Comment: Yes - part of the reason chef-solo exists is to run as a non-root user. What are the permissions on that file? I checked my install and I don't even have that file but everyone had read perms on /opt/chef. Also, depending on your version of chef, have you tried chef-zero? http://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-in-local-mode

Comment: It turned out to be permission issue on the file. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change permissions on a few files/folders (PID file, cache folders, logs) but other than that Chef can run as any user.

That said, it sounds like what you really want is to run the installer a different user which you can do more directly:

```
execute '/whatever/oracleintaller' do
   user 'me'
end
```